# How to protect longitude/latitude values stealing from site

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, google-maps-api-3

I have javascript function mixed with ASP MVC Razor that get data from database and based on that data draw markers on google map.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Locations)
            {                
                 @:addMarker(@item.Latitude, @item.Longitude, map);
             }
```

The problem begins after I load this markers on map.
If I open page source in browser this foreach loop look like this:

```
addMarker(20.917701, 44.022, map);
addMarker(20.927701, 44.052, map);
addMarker(20.937701, 44.062, map);
addMarker(20.947701, 44.072, map);
...
```

Is it possible to somehow hide this coordinates values? My application business is based on these coordinates and I don't wan't that somebody make a script and get all coordinates from my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is, as third parties (Google or others) need access to these co-ordinates outside of the page request to create the map, so if you found some way to hide these details then Google maps would not be able to supply a map with the markers (as it requests these details outside of the page request.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea:
You could download the coordinates via AJAX from an HTTPS secured adress.
This way, people cannot sniff the traffic.

Instead of runnning addMarker with hardcoded values, you can then pass the parameters from the AJAX call into the maps control.

To secure the AJAX service from external grabbing, you generate a temporary token on the server side. You embedd the token into the ASP.NET MVC page (into the ajax call).
The AJAX service checks for the value of the token..

It's not 100% secure, but it decreases the risk of stealing your coordinates in my opinion.

IF it needs to be 100% secure, you need to render the final image on your own server, including the points-of-interest.

Comment: Even if you get the data in a secure fashion, once it's in the browser anyone can get it with a bit of effort. Altering a Google Maps image on your server is against the Terms of Service (although you may be able to find a map supplier who does allow that).